# SQL error Oracle Trigger on Delete

Tags: oracle, triggers, delete-row

I am a first timer in Oracle and using Netbean IDE 8 and I am trying to prevent deletion of a Hotel from Hotel Table if Room Table has Room details for the Hotel. These 2 tables are on 2 different sites so have to use trigger. I tried the following code but it throws error like following with sql error on line 6, 10, 13, 14,

> [Exception, Error code 6,550, SQLState 65000] ORA-06550: line 4,
>   column 19: PLS-00049: bad bind variable '' ORA-06550: line 4, column
>   30: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one
>   of the following:

the table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE Hotel
(
  HotelID number not null,
  HotelName varchar2(100) not null,
  HotelType varchar2(10) not null,
  ConstrYear varchar2(10) null,
  Country varchar2 (100) not null,
  City varchar2 (50) not null,
  Address varchar2 (100) not null, 
  ContactNo varchar2(50) not null,
  Email varchar2(100) null,
  CONSTRAINT Hotel_pk PRIMARY KEY (HotelID)
);
```

and for Room

```
CREATE TABLE Room 
(
 RoomID number not null, 
 HotelID raw(16) not null, 
 RoomNo number not null,
 RoomType varchar2(20) not null, 
 Price numeric(10,2) not null, 
 RoomDesc varchar2(255) not null, 
 CONSTRAINT Room_pk PRIMARY KEY (RoomID),
);
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHECK_Room
BEFORE DELETE on Hotel
FOR each ROW
declare
  rowcount number;
begin
  SELECT COUNT(HotelID) INTO rowcount 
  from ROOM@site1
  where HotelID = :OLD.HotelID;
  if rowcount>0 
  THEN
     Raise_Application_Error (-20100, 'This Hotel has room details in Room table.');
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: One error - you are declaring `rowcount` variable, but using `if rowcnt>0`.  Also use `set define off`command to avoid "bad bind variable" error.

Comment: The PLS-00049 error suggests your hotel table doesn't have a column called HotelId. Can you add the structures of both tables to your question? The PLS-00103 error may just be because you don't have a trailling /, but the line number reference is a bit odd. Which client and you running this in, and how? Wondering if it is just not handling PL/SQL code properly, and is confused by the semicolons.

Comment: I am using NetBean IDE 8. rowcont >0 was a typo. I am using rowcount > 0.

Comment: None of the examples [in the NetBeans docs](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/oracle-db.html) show PL/SQL. I still suspect the semicolons are tripping it up then. Are you using the 'execute command' method? I might be worth trying the 'run file' method from a script file, but I doubt it will help. I'd suggest you use a different IDE for this stuff, like the free [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html). Or just SQL\*Plus. Or, if you really can't, write your own trivial Java program to run that over JDBC *8-)

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole. Yes it seems to be the NetBeans problem. I used SQL Developer and worked. It throws error, but at least it compiled and worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should work for you, provided your database link is in good shape.
I'd recommend staying away from using a reserved word as a variable name.    One common convention is to prefix variable names with "v" as in this example.
I'd also recommend qualifying schema names over the database link.  `THE_USER` is a placeholder here as is `THE_OTHER_DATABASE`.  Please replace with `site1`, etc. as needed.
First create the tables, in your case in two databases:

```
--This database
CREATE TABLE HOTEL(HOTELID NUMBER);
--(On the other database)
CREATE TABLE ROOM(HOTELID NUMBER);
-- ... Set up database link

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHECK_ROOM
BEFORE DELETE ON HOTEL
FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE
    V_ROWCOUNT NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(HOTELID)
    INTO V_ROWCOUNT
    FROM THE_USER.ROOM@THE_OTHER_DATABASE
    WHERE ROOM.HOTELID = :OLD.HOTELID;
    IF V_ROWCOUNT > 0
    THEN
      Raise_Application_Error(-20100, 'This Hotel has room details in Room table.');
    END IF;
  END;
  /
```

Then test it:

```
--Here
INSERT INTO HOTEL VALUES(19);
COMMIT;
--There
INSERT INTO ROOM VALUES(19);
COMMIT;
```

Then:

```
DELETE FROM HOTEL;
DELETE FROM HOTEL
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20100: This Hotel has room details in Room table.
```

Comment: I tried exactly what you showed here and tried on same connection, but still having error as follows, [Exception, Error code 6,550, SQLState 65000] ORA-06550: line 5, column 26:
PLS-00049: bad bind variable ''
ORA-06550: line 5, column 37:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

Comment: Thanks @MohammedS Do you have access to clients like SQLPlus, SQLcl or SQLDeveloper to compare the behavior in another tool against netbeans?  Alex Poole has a good question above to consider the editor in addition to the plsql text.  If you have access to another client, it would be good to see if the behavior repeats similarly.  Also can you confirm for me, when you tried this, did you run the whole example above including the CREATE TABLEs, only replacing the schema and db link?  Thanks

Comment: Thanks @alexgibbs. yep ran the whole script including create table at once except delete function. Replaced schema and db link. I do not have any other IDE, but I will try to get one and let you know the behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @MohammedS sounds good,  I'll wait to hear how this behaves in another editor.  I believe Alex Poole had some suggestions, but I'd add SQLcl as well.  It is free, supported by oracle and is lightweight.  It is a java command-line app.  You can try it here:  [sqlcl](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/downloads/index.html)

Comment: Thanks @alexgibbs. I tried it on SQL Developer and it did work, but it compiled with error. The trigger prevents from deleting, but throwing error as well. The output as as follows. I am trying on SQLcl now.   Error starting at line : 1 in command -
DELETE FROM HOTEL
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-20100: This Hotel has room details in Room table.
ORA-06512: at "USER.CHECK_ROOM", line 10
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'USER.CHECK_ROOM'

Comment: @MohammedS Thanks for the follow up.  This looks good; the exceptions you are seeing are normal--the `ORA-20100` is what we put in the trigger itself to prevent deleting `HOTEL` records referenced by `ROOM`s.  The `04088` and `06512` are helper-messages to let any caller whose `DELETE` is blocked by the trigger see that it was a TRIGGER that denied the `DELETE` and where in the code the error occurred, in case they want to look into it.  If these `TABLE`s were in one database with a foreign key instead, it would also raise an exception (`ORA-02292`).  Thanks